# Markdown + Mathjax => PDF

Tags: pdf, compiling, markdown

I've used LaTeX a lot in the past, but now, when comparing with StackExchange's great [editor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), I find it tedious, for short documents (< 2 pages), to have to use **pure LaTeX**.

For a short document, instead of having 30 lines as introduction:

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
+ <lots of other things>
...
```

**I'd like to write my short document with MarkDown + Math**, like on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

## Question:

Is there an offline compiler such that

```
compilemarkdown exercice.tex
```

would produce a PDF from this:

```
#Title

Here is a *short document* including Markdown and Math, here is the equation:

$$f(x)=x^2$$

___

Proof: ... 

This is **bold**.
```

Comment: Well, not a solution, but many LaTeX editors allow to use templates. So you can create one and then just open it. I created one and then I just call it on Linux terminal `fastex` and the editor opens with my minimal template.

Comment: @Sigur I already use templates, but this is not really a solution. To sum up the idea : now that I'm used to mix Markdown and Latex/Mathjax  (thanks StackExchange!), I *really want* to have this great way of writing short documents offline. No more 30 lines of `\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`... I want to keep the goodness of StackEdit / StackExchange's editor offline, as a compiler like `latex`.

Comment: So you want to be able to take a Markdown file like the Markdown code you posted and turn it into a PDF? Do you have to be able to use packages like `amsmath`, `babel`, etc.?

Comment: try pandoc's new non-latex pdf generation.

Comment: @Null I want a simple tool, that can convert the code I posted `#Title ... This is **bold**.` into a PDF. Without having to `\usepackage`, without having to `\begin{document}`, etc. In short : I want math.stackexchange 's great online editor *as an offline tool* that can produce PDF.

Comment: @Basj Okay, I think pandoc will work for you then. I've posted an answer that uses pandoc.

Comment: You might consider [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/).

Comment: Why would you want to do this in LaTeX? There is a ton of markdown editors which do exactly that. You write markdown + mathjax, then export as either PDF or LaTeX. There are cloud solutions, Windows solutions, Linux solutions...

Comment: @rumtscho I don't want to do it in LaTeX. But the compiler must use LaTeX in order to render the math parts. See accepted answer. I already know the online cloud solutions (StackEdit.io, etc.), what Windows solutions are you thinking about?

Comment: @Basj I use CuteMarkEd on Windows and Remarkable or ReText on Linux, I think some of them are cross platform. I almost never need MathJax, but I think they support it in principle. You'd have to take a look at the feature lists. They are certainly much more stable than StackEdit.io (which has already lost my information once or twice, I suspect due to bad cookie sync). And they don't have LaTeX like formatting, but you can use a custom CSS with them. The included styles are also quite good for everyday use.

Comment: @rumtscho I just installed and tried CuteMarkEd, it's nice, but you can't write math... So it's not a solution... How do you write math inside CuteMarkEd? (I tried *Extra > Math support* but it doesn't work...)

Comment: I don't even know if CuteMarkEd has both Markdown and Mathjax. Some editors have it, some don't. You'll have to look in the features. Also, if a Windows application is good for your case, you could go and ask on Software Recommendations, or use another service for finding a Markdown editor with the features you need.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is possible with [`pandoc`](http://pandoc.org/). If the Markdown you've posted is in the file `test.md` you can generate a PDF called `test.pdf` with the following command:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf
```

The PDF file looks like this:

[image]

`pandoc` converts the Markdown to a PDF using LaTeX. It recognizes that the input is Markdown from the file extension, but if you use a different file extension you can include `-f markdown` to instruct `pandoc` to convert from Markdown. The `-o test.pdf` part of the command tells `pandoc` to output a PDF with the given filename.

The `pandoc` website has a nice [getting started guide](http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html).

Comment: Really really nice. Installed and already working! This is really LaTeX's future. I will always use this for small documents now! Wonderful.

Comment: @Basj Glad to hear you like it!

Comment: If someone has a `SublimeText` `.sublime-build` build system file to share, I'm in heaven :)

Comment: If the markdown is based on Jekyll and has used some plugins, is this method still work? I have tried a simple case to convert my [vita.md](https://github.com/i2000s/en) page yet failed.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) for notes and small documents. It's really a journal or diary, but it lets me to take quick notes with (modified) markdown and MathJax (with `webkit`), and then, if necessary, to export to html or pdf or LaTeX.

If I type:

```
= Title =

Here is a //short document// including Markdown and Math, here is the equation:

$$f(x)=x^2$$

====================

Proof: ... 

This is **bold**.
```

I get this (edition mode):

[image: Editor]

and this (preview):

[image: Preview]

Then you export to pdf, which looks like this:

[image: PDF output]

(Output font can be changed from Preferences).

Answer (score 3):

What I meant by my original comment is this: with `pandoc -t html5 -o test.pdf test.md` you can bypass LaTeX entirely; you are only required to install [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is a single executable like pandoc on windows.

Results as follows:

[image: Result with wkhtmltopdf, without LaTeX]

You may control the output with css.

Comment: this should be a good answer!